# I want a paragraph to get the line through style whenever a checkbox is checked and vise versa

Tags: javascript, html

## It doesn't work as expected

I managed to make it work in this way :

```
 <div class="noteContainer">
            <p class="title">Hello World</p>
            <p class="note">This is the hello world note!
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o noteEdit" title="Edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <input onclick="setLineThrough()" type="checkbox" name="done" class="cbDone">
            </p>
 </div>
```

```
let checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("cbDone");
const setLineThrough = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
            checkBoxes[i].parentElement.style.textDecorationLine = "line-through";
        } else {
            checkBoxes[i].parentElement.style.textDecorationLine = "none";
        }
    }
};
```

### It wasn't exactly what I wanted

But then the `line through` also goes through my `icon` and to the `checkbox` so I decided to get them out of the `<p>` and made some changes and I was expecting it to work since they were so similar but it just adds the `line through` but it does not remove the `line through` when the `checkbox` is `unchecked`!

```
<div class="noteContainer">
            <p class="title">Hello World</p>
            <p class="note">This is the hello world note!</p>
            <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o noteEdit" title="Edit" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <input onclick="setLineThrough()" type="checkbox" name="done" class="cbDone">
      </div>
```

```
let checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("cbDone");
let notePara = document.getElementsByClassName("note");
const setLineThrough = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
            notePara[i].style.textDecorationLine = "line-through";
        } else {
            notePara[i].parentElement.style.textDecorationLine = "none";
        }
    }
};
```

What is wrong with my second iteration? I just can't find it.
Also take note that there are some `css` in my code but I don't think it is needed here.

Comment: try this in second code => `notePara[i].style.textDecorationLine = "none";` - you do *not* need `parentElement` in this line!

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Yep. I'm blind :D it is fixed now

Comment: Glad to hear that, Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to delete one instance of `.parentElement` from your JavaScript.

Your JavaScript will then look like this:

```
let checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("cbDone");
let notePara = document.getElementsByClassName("note");
const setLineThrough = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
            notePara[i].style.textDecorationLine = "line-through";
        } else {
            notePara[i].style.textDecorationLine = "none";
        }
    }
};
```